# Android Validating the user input in edittext not working in adapter?

Tags: android, validation, adapter

I want to take the first and last name from a user and the number of input changes dynamically; while validating the input it does not work.

The code for  validating is ;

```
public class IndividualAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Individual> {
    List<Individual> individualList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public IndividualAdapter(Context context, List<Individual> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.inidividual_list, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        individualList = objects;
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        public EditText edtfName;
        public EditText edtlName;
        private TextView txtType;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        Individual ind = getItem(position);
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.inidividual_list, parent, true);
            holder.edtfName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fst_name);
            holder.edtlName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lst_name);
            holder.txtType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.typeValue);
        }
        holder.txtType.setText(ind.getType());
        String fName = holder.edtfName.getText().toString().trim();
        String lName = holder.edtlName.getText().toString().trim();
        if (fName.equals(" ")) {
            holder.edtfName.setError("First Name Can not be empty");
            holder.edtfName.setText("First Name Can not be empty");
        }
        if (lName.equals(" ")) {
            holder.edtlName.setError("Last Name Can not be empty");
            holder.edtlName.setText("Last Name Can not be empty");
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

My app crashes as soon as I click on the next button after filing the text field.
Without filling the field it does not show up any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you check null exception in your activity class.I think what you are doing is not a good practice of coding.However why don't  you try like this below

```
if(fName!=null && fName.length()>0)
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried all the solutions as mentioned above but, what happened is , I passed to this activity it shows error before entering anydata to edit text field , and after i enter it need to passed to next activity but it does not ??

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText txtUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
String strUserName = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
if (strUserName.trim().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "plz enter your name ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
or use the TextUtils class like this :

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strUserName) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "plz enter your name ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're **trimming** the text and checking `if (fName.equals(" "))` .Try removing that space and check like this `if (fName.equals(""))`